# Tcl/Tk treeview

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to run a simple Tcl/Tk gui application using the following code:

```
package require Tk
ttk::treeview .tree -columns "Creator Year" -displaycolumns "Year Creator" 
.tree heading Creator -text "Creator" -anchor center
.tree heading Year -text "Year" -anchor center
pack .tree
```

I am running this through my  tclsh console and it works fine. However, when i close the GUI window my application creates,  and run the code a second time i get the following error:

> this isn't a Tk applicationNULL main window
>
> invalid command name ".tree"
>
> invalid command name ".tree"
>
> can't invoke "pack" command:  application has been destroyed

So my questions is this why does this fail when i run the code a second time?

if i start the tclsh agian i get the same thing. works first time but not second time after closing the GUI window my application creates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
package require Tk
toplevel .t
ttk::treeview .t.tree -columns "Creator Year" -displaycolumns "Year Creator"
.t.tree heading Creator -text "Creator" -anchor center
.t.tree heading Year -text "Year" -anchor center
pack .t.tree
```

The only difference is that you create a toplevel widget (looks and acts like the application window, but you can have several). Make your tree widget a child of the toplevel instead of `.`: `.t.tree` instead of `.tree`. Now you can close the toplevel and open it again by running the same code.

You can’t close the application window and later run Tk code in the same process: it’s a limitation of the windowing system.

Documentation:
[toplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/toplevel.htm)